# With a MySQL GROUP BY, how do I control the default value to choose in non-aggregated columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by

I have the following table:

```
type |     description  | rank
------------------------|-------
1    | "foo bar baz"    | 1
1    | "bar foo baz"    | 4
2    | "baz bar foo"    | 2
3    | "bar baz foo"    | 3
```

I want to `GROUP BY type`, and for all other columns, return the value associated with `MAX(rank)`. Obviously `MAX(rank)` is easy, but how do I get `"description ORDER BY rank DESC"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to select max(rank) and self-join to get the associated description

```
select t1.type, t1.max_rank, t2.description from (
    select max(rank) max_rank, type
    from mytable
    group by type
) t1 join mytable t2 on t1.type = t2.type and t1.max_rank = t2.rank
order by t1.max_rank desc
```

or using `not exists`

```
select * from mytable t1
where not exists (
    select 1 from mytable t2
    where t2.type = t1.type
    and t2.rank > t1.rank
)
order by rank desc
```